# string.replace() with global (g) not working in a weird way

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, wordpress, replace

I'm trying to use javaScript's .replace function to replace square brackets from a string but it's not working. My code:

```
var str = document.getElementById('string-input-field').value;
str = str.replace(/[/g, '&#91;').replace(/]/g, '&#93;');
```

The weird part is that, it's not giving any errors but instead of replacing [ and ] it's replacing only few alphabets. So for example if I try this:

```
var str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
str = str.replace(/[/g, '6').replace(/]/g, '6');
```

I get '6b6d6f6hijk6mno6q6stuvwxyz'. So the alphabets 'a c e g l p r' are getting replaced. Also I tried setting the variable as a simple string, like above, and also by getting the value from the input field, but still the same problem.

Please let me know what's wrong, or if there is any other way I can achieve the same thing.

Ps. I'm working on localhost, and this page is getting loaded in the admin area of Wordpress (post.php - The Edit page).

**Update**

I tried the following after @p.s.w.g answers:

```
str = 'aaaaa[bbbbbb]ccccc';
str = str.replace(/\[/g, '&#91;').replace(/]/g, '&#93;');
```

And I get the same back: aaaaa[bbbbbb]ccccc. However, the old problem is fixed like @p.s.w.g said. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is a special character in regular expressions that begins a character class, which continues until it encounters a `]`. The parser considers all of `[/g, '6').replace(/]` to be a character class. A character class will match any character (or range of characters specified inside the brackets. In this case that means any `/`, `g`, (space), `'`, `6`, `)`, `.`, `r`, `e`, `p`, `l`, `a`, `c`, or `(`, character.

Try escaping the `[` character like this (note that it's not necessary to escape the `]` because it's not a special character unless it it's part of a character class):

```
str = str.replace(/\[/g, '&#91;').replace(/]/g, '&#93;');
```

For example:

```
var str = "[foo] [bar]";
str = str.replace(/\[/g, '&#91;').replace(/]/g, '&#93;');
console.log(str); // "&#91;foo&#93; &#91;bar&#93;"
```

---

Regarding your update, it's possible that whatever tool your using is silently converting the `&#91;` and `&#93;` back to a `[` and `]`. If that's the case, you may also want to escape the `&` to avoid this:

```
str = str.replace(/\[/g, '&amp;#91;').replace(/]/g, '&amp;#93;');
```

But this might break down in other cases, it's probably better to use a replacement method like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\[|]/g, function(c) { 
    return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';' 
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan Not quite, that will match a `[` or `|` character followed by a `]` character.

Comment: The OP is trying to escape the brackets with html entities, so the alternative simplified example might not be relevant unless you replace `'6'` with a function returning `&#91;` or `&#93;`

Comment: I tried this: str.replace(/\[/g, '&#91;').replace(/]/g, '&#93;') but now it is not replacing anything. Stackoverflow is ignoring the forward slash for some reason, I'll update my question.

Comment: @user3570481 See my updated answer for my thoughts on what might be going on and some alternative solutions

Comment: Seems like my browser was converting the codes to the brackets and it's working great now :) Thank you so much!, I would probably be homeless without StackOverflow and other people's help :p